# How to get localized file size units in Swift

Tags: swift, localization, foundation

I tried the following code:

```
    let units: [ByteCountFormatter.Units] = [.useBytes, .useKB, .useMB, .useGB, .useTB, .usePB, .useEB, .useZB, .useYBOrHigher]

    let localizedDescriptions = units.map { (unit) -> String in
        let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.includesCount = false
        formatter.includesUnit = true
        formatter.allowedUnits = [unit]
        formatter.countStyle = .file
        return formatter.string(fromByteCount: .max)
    }
```

And expect it to be **localized** according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter).

> Class
>
> ByteCountFormatter
>
> A formatter that converts a byte count value
>   into a localized description that is formatted with the appropriate
>   byte modifier (KB, MB, GB and so on).

But unfortunately, I got only:

```
["bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"]
```

I tested:

- Switch system locale and reload my mac(Saw different file size format in finder: "КБ", "МБ"... instead of "KB", "MB")
- Playground/macOS template project.
- Switched "Application language" in macOS template project.

PS

In any case thanks for reading this...

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what was your expected output?

Comment: @phi I guess that `KB` should be `КБ` in Russian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set a `locale` to `ByteCountFormatter`, but you can with `MeasurementFormatter`.

Here is a sample (modify the `unitStyle` and other properties as you need).

```
let units: [UnitInformationStorage] = [.bytes, .kilobytes, .megabytes, .gigabytes, .terabytes, .petabytes, .zettabytes, .yottabytes]

let localizedDescriptions = units.map({ unit -> String in

    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    formatter.unitStyle = .short
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU") //hard coded here, I guess it takes the current one
    return formatter.string(from: unit)
})
```

Output:

```
$> ["Б", "кБ", "МБ", "ГБ", "ТБ", "ПБ", "ZB", "YB"]
```

Zetta & Yotta aren't translated though?

From [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/formatter/):

> `ByteCountFormatter`, `EnergyFormatter`, `MassFormatter`, `LengthFormatter`, and `MKDistanceFormatter` are superseded by `MeasurementFormatter`.
>   **Legacy Measure:** `ByteCountFormatter`
>   **Measurement Formatter Unit**: UnitInformationStorage